# Why does my laptop boot really quickly with this new SSD but reboots extremely slowly?

Tags: ssd

OK so I have a Samsung NP700Z5C-S02UB (Series 7 Chronos 15.6'') and I just replaced it's old HDD with a new Samsung V-NAND 850 EVO with 500GB.
The PC boots up (after shutdown) in about 7 seconds. But to restart it (whether new programs were recently installed or not), it takes nearly 4 minutes, and I've tested this several times.
What gives?

Also, I cannot seem to find ExpressCache anywhere on this new hard drive. It came on the computer originally.

It was done on a clean install of Windows 10. The original hard drive came with Windows 8, if this matters.

Comment: ExpressCache seems to be only for cases where a small SSD and a larger mechanical disk are used together. it would provide no meaningful advantage over just using an SSD. https://www.condusiv.com/partners/oem/technologies/expresscache/ As for your reboot time, have you disabled the option "clear page file at system shutdown"? search the registry for `ClearPageFileAtShutdown` and make sure its value is 0. How long does a shutdown take, as a proportion of the reboot time?

Comment: Is that the way the computer was before I installed the ssd? Also, could that have any adverse effects on it?

Comment: I just did what u said and it was at zero. But rebooting is still taking much longer than with the HDD. With this SSD, it takes 4 minutes. The HDD was much quicker for reboot.

Comment: "Also, I cannot seem to find `ExpressCache` anywhere on this new hard drive. It came on the computer originally." - So install it.  `ExpressCache` is third-party software.  My guess is that its equivalent to the Intel RST.  Be sure you are not booting in legacy mode, booting in legacy mode, would explain the 4 minute boot times.

Comment: how do I make sure I'm not booting in legacy mode? Also, does this have anything to do with ExpressCache?

Comment: can I get some more help? PLEASE???? I'm desperate! I spent 300 on both the drive and install!

Comment: I would take it back to where you left your 300 at.  Honestly they owe you a working computer right?  Sounds like something might have just got missed.  They might have messed with the BIOS settings, very hard to tell since there are no actual errors.

Comment: could it have been because the shop I took it to used an unlicensed version of Windows 10? I actually had the whole thing reversed, and then afterwards, found out the license key for my Windows, which I would've given them had I known it.